# Django transforming an old url to new syntax

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to use this app in my project: https://github.com/s1n4/django-favorite
but it has old url syntax and I did not understand how to transform it to new url syntax.
The url that I wanna transform:

```
{% url favorite.views.add_or_remove target_model target_object_id %}
```

Its exact form in html:

```
<button class="btn favorite" href="{% url 'favorite.views.add_or_remove' %}" model="{{ target_model }}" id="target_{{ target_object_id }}">
```

I know the syntax has changed with Django 1.5 and I tried to use this version:

```
{% url 'favorite.views.add_or_remove' target_model target_object_id %}
```

It also did not work.
It says:

```
Reverse for 'favorite.views.add_or_remove' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Edit:
Its template tag can help to understand:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def favorite_button(context, target):
    user = context['request'].user

    # do nothing when user isn't authenticated
    if not user.is_authenticated():
        return ''

    target_model = '.'.join((target._meta.app_label, target._meta.object_name))
    target_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(target)
    target_object_id = target.id
    fav_count = Favorite.objects.filter(target_content_type=target_content_type,
                                        target_object_id=target_object_id).count()
    undo = False
    if user.favorite_set.filter(target_content_type=target_content_type,
                                target_object_id=target_object_id):
        undo = True

    return render_to_string('favorite/button.html',
                            {'target_model': target_model, 'target_object_id': target_object_id,
                             'fav_count': fav_count, 'undo': undo})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that application is in use in production (in which we used Django 1.4) I cannot patch the application to make it compatible with Django 1.5+. But there is a pull-request that I kept open for such a situation. Here it is: https://github.com/s1n4/django-favorite/pull/1 It might solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The URL has no arguments:

```
url(r'^add-or-remove$', 'add_or_remove'),
```

and neither does that view:

```
def add_or_remove(request):
```

The URL tag in the HTML there also has no arguments:

```
{% url favorite.views.add_or_remove %}
```

To convert that to the new syntax it would be:

```
{% url 'favorite.views.add_or_remove' %}
```

After that you can use the template tag as described in the README:

```
{% load favorite_tags %}

{% for comment in post.comments %}
  {% favorite_button comment %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I edited the exact form of link in html. Can u consider it too?